# TypeError: Cannot set property 'treeGrid' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using jqxTreeGrid widget and running into a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'treeGrid' of null` error.

I've come across some sources that said that the div which the table is being attached to is not being found but I `console.log` the div and it was found.

Any other suggestions what might be causing this issue?

```
VIEW
<div id="treeGrid"></div>


SCRIPT
var tableDiv = $("#treeGrid");
    var tableData = <%=raw @array_with_data.to_json%>;
    var treeSource, treeData;

    treeSource = {
        dataType: "json",
        dataFields: [
            { name: "id", type: "number" },
            { name: "foo_id", type: "number" },
            { name: "foo_name", type: "string" },
            { name: "bar_id", type: "number" },
            { name: "bar_name", type: "string" },
            { name: "noob_name", type: "string" }
        ],
        hierarchy: {
            keyDataField: { name: "id" },
            parentDataField: { name: "foo_id" }
        },
        id: "id",
        localData: tableData
    };

    treeData = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(treeSource);
    treeData.dataBind();

    // build table as a tree table:
    tableDiv.jqxTreeGrid({
        width: "100%",
        source: treeData,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: true,
        selectionMode: "singleRow",
        columns: [
            { text: "ID", dataField: "id", hidden: true },
            { text: "Foo ID", dataField: "foo_id", columnGroup: "foo", width: "20%" },
            { text: "Foo Name", dataField: "foo_name", columnGroup: "foo", width: "20%" },
            { text: "Bar ID", dataField: "bar_id", columnGroup: "bar", width: "20%" },
            { text: "Bar Name", dataField: "bar_name", columnGroup: "bar", width: "20%" },
            { text: "Noob Name", dataField: "noob_name", columnGroup: "noob", width: "20%" }
        ],
        columnGroups: [
            { text: "Foo", name: "foo" },
            { text: "Bar", name: "bar" },
            { text: "Noob", name: "noob" }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: so that means if you place console log right before your code it works there? And data is being printed to page as valid javascript variable?

Comment: If I was to place `console.log(tableDiv.text());` just before the `tableDiv.jqxTreeGrid({` and place some text inside the said div... then the text appears in the console.

Comment: Would check issues tracker for the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My problem was, that I included jqxdatatable.js AFTER jqxtreegrid.js

WRONG:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqwidgets/jqxtreegrid.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js"></script>
```

CORRECT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqwidgets/jqxtreegrid.js"></script>
```

When I put it before the other include, it worked